# How can I keep bears out of the trash?

Tags: trash

I live in an area where very large bears (500 - 1,000 lbs.) get into the trash every other night. It is a large trash can with wheels and a heavy duty lid. It is surrounded by cinder blocks with pallets placed over the cinder blocks. The bears have no struggle throwing everything around and making a mess.

What sort of repellant can I use to make the bear leave my trash alone?

[image]

Comment: LOL, I heard that at Yellowstone bears will rip the doors off SUVs to get at food they know is inside the car.

Comment: you can use the method that they use when protecting food from bears while camping. get a rope and tie it up in a tree out of their reach

Comment: does mace or pepper spray work on bears???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you could use a chain and padlock to secure the lid closed. You probably wouldn't even need a padlock, just something like a 'D' shackle which I wouldn't think a bear would be able to unscrew.

[image: Bin locked with chain and padlock] 
[image: D Shackle]

There are also commercial bin locking devices available if you want a pre-made solution:

[Binlock](http://www.binlock.com/)

[Easylifetools](http://www.easylifetools.co.uk/wheelie%20bin%20lock.htm)

Answer (score 6):

Bears are intelligent, have long claws and are immensely strong. Odor will not deter them. There are a number of bear-resistant trash containers on the market, e.g. [Bearsaver](http://www.bearsaver.com/), though I expect they're a bit pricey.

For small amounts of trash, suspending a receptacle with rope and pulley from a tall tree might work, though small bears do climb.

If you decide to create your own container, see the hints at [BearSmart.com](http://www.bearsmart.com/managing-communities/waste-management/), such as reducing odor from food waste, fitting lids with recessed latches, and making the container strong and tip-resistant.

[See what a bear can do to a "container" such as a car.](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2782560/Furious-brown-bear-stages-terrifying-revenge-attack-hunter-shot-leg-returns-night-rip-vehicle-pieces.html)

Comment: LOL hoist the trash into a tree. You live in the city don't you?

Answer (score 3):

The only way to protect trash from a bear without using specific bear-proof containers is to build an enclosure with a VERY rugged door, think steel, with multiple latches. Looks like you have some cinderblocks, so I guess that is one step in that direction. Maybe hire a mason to build an enclosure?

Option 2 is to forget the plastic things and use actual bear-proof containers, which are generally 55-gallon steel drums (think oil barrels with locking lids). You can buy them. They are a complete pain in the ass to use.

There is no way to "repel" a bear. (Leonardo DiCaprio can tell you about that.)